# How to generate freedraw line with the freedrawing`s data

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

i  am working the online-classroom`s program , the teacher and student can do the freedraw and see the other`s freedraw at the same time.

i can get the data from others fressdraw with the methods (eg, toJson/ToObject).

Now, how can i draw a freedraw with the data?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Freedraw is a fabric.Path().

So you have to call

```
var obj = new fabric.Path(freeData, {fill: '', stroke: 'black'});
```

Data has to be in the string format or array of commands format.